# Como posso usar dois métodos em uma mesma linha em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como poderia ordenar os métodos das duas ultimas linhas de código comnetado, de modo que funcione nesse código:

```
# É criada a hash 'pontuações' a qual ira armazenar e ao mesmo tempo linkar os nomes as pontuações
pontuações = { }
arquivo = open("results.txt")
for linha in arquivo:
    (nome, pontuação) = linha.split()
    # A variável pontuações com a chave tendo como valor as variáveis do array 'pontuação' e tem como valor as variáveis do array 'nome'
    pontuações[pontuação] = nome
print("As pontuações mais altas são : ")
# Pode ser traduzido essa linha de código como 'para cada_pontuação(nova variável criada) em pontuações'retornar um array com as chaves do hash' '
for cada_pontuação in pontuações.keys():
    # Mostra os valores(os nomes neste caso) assosciados as chaves de 'pontuações' juntamente com 'pontuou' e mostra as chaves da variável 'cada_pontuação'
    print(pontuações[cada_pontuação] + '    pontuou ' + cada_pontuação)
'''
pontuações.keys(.sort(reverse = True))
print(pontuações)
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é questão de "usar dois métodos na mesma linha" - é só que o "sort" não retorna nenhum valor: ele ordena a lista internamente.

Mas o Python tem também a função built-in `sorted`- ela cria uma nova lista ordenada a partir de uma sequência, e retorna essa nova sequência - então pode ser usada como parâmetro para outra função:

```
print(sorted(pontuações))
```

Mas nunca deixe "não da pra fazer na mesma linha" atrapalhar sua programação - não é sobre por em menos linhas. No caso de Python, especificamente, a questão é "como deixar o programa mais legível para quem vier depois de mim poder continuar".

No caso do `sort` existe  `sorted` que permite colocar tudo numa expressão só, mas se não houvesse, não há nenhum problema em se usar várias linhas de código para expressar uma operação.

Answer (score -1):

Se as *keys* de um dicionário forem números (`float` ou `int`), `list(dict.keys())` retorna uma lista ordenada delas. Exemplo:

```
d=dict({5.1:"asd", 2.3:"bbjs", 4.0:"sdad", 3.6:"dsf"})

list(d.keys())

Out[54]: [2.3, 3.6, 4.0, 5.1]
```

Para obter uma lista ordenada na ordem inversa:

```
sorted(list(d.keys()), reverse=True)

Out[58]: [5.1, 4.0, 3.6, 2.3]
```

Adaptando o seu código:

```
# É criada a hash 'pontuações' a qual ira armazenar e ao mesmo tempo linkar os nomes as pontuações
pontuações = { }
arquivo = open("results.txt")
for linha in arquivo:
    (nome, pontuação) = linha.split()
    # A variável pontuações com a chave tendo como valor as variáveis do array 'pontuação' e tem como valor as variáveis do array 'nome'
    pontuações[float(pontuação)] = nome # provavelmente pontuação é uma string por ser parte de uma linha de texto, force-a a ser um float
print("As pontuações mais altas são : ")
# Pode ser traduzido essa linha de código como 'para cada_pontuação(nova variável criada) em pontuações'retornar um array com as chaves do hash' '
for cada_pontuação in pontuações.keys():
    # Mostra os valores(os nomes neste caso) assosciados as chaves de 'pontuações' juntamente com 'pontuou' e mostra as chaves da variável 'cada_pontuação'
    print(pontuações[cada_pontuação] + '    pontuou ' + cada_pontuação)

print( sorted(list(pontuações.keys()), reverse=True) )
```

Comment: *"Se as keys de um dicionário forem números (float ou int), `list(dict.keys())` retorna uma lista ordenada delas."* **Isso é falso**. Pode ter vindo ordenado por sorte no seu exemplo, mas não é algo que o python faça, então você não pode contar com isso como sendo uma invariante. Se tentar outros exemplos vai perceber que isso não acontece. Além disso, a partir do python 3.6 `.keys()` retorna as chaves na mesma ordem que foram inseridas.